# Weird Issue with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, xcode6

My app was working fine. But from last hour it is crashing giving me a log:

```
Channel name must start with a letter: 2 (Code: 112, Version: 1.7.2)
```

I am using Parse push notification service and following code to subscribe a channel:

```
    NSString *str =[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userEmail"]; //asd@lop.com


str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@"
                                     withString:@"-"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."
                                     withString:@"-"];



 PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:str forKey:@"channels"];
currentInstallation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser]; //app crashes here

[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

I haven't changed anything. I checked earlier versions of my code and they also crashing at same point. What is the issue i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: What is `str`? that would be pretty much essential to know.

Comment: What is the output if you put `NSLog(@"%@", str);` just before the `addUniqueObject` line?

Comment: @Fogmeister if i enter email like stack@gmail.com then the output would be stack-gmail-com

Comment: That isn't what I asked. Put the log code in. Make the app crash. Let me know what the log statement said.

Comment: The error log you are getting is telling you that `str` is "2" which is not valid because it begins with a number.

Comment: that is impossible.after debuging i can c that in str their is asd-asd-asd how can 2 comes in it

Comment: Read what the error means. Google it. That 2 in the error is the name of the channel you are trying to add. And it is causing error. Maybe try logging out what channels are added on the currentInstallation. Maybe it has a 2 in there?

Comment: @Fogmeister  even when I use hard coded chanel like **[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"mychn" forKey:@"channels"];** the app crahses

Comment: Exactly. So that suggests that there is already a channel called "2" in the current installation. All I am doing is telling you what that error means. I'm not making it up. That 2 means that you are trying to save a channel called "2". You need to find and remove that.

Comment: @Fogmeister  how can i find.. i tried but i havent found 2

Comment: What is the result of `NSLog(@"%@", [currentInstallation objectForKey:@"channels"]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine and according to what you said that it used to be working I'd think you should try to uninstall/re-install the app on your device and try again.